24.04 - gdm3 crash... how to report from terminal? Reporting problem?
This appears to be caused by sudo apt install fuse...

Of some peculiar reason gdm3 crashed on me (on a fairly fresh install of 24.04).
/var/log files didn't appear to tell anything as I glanced through them (not all).
.. but then /var/crash/ had a file, so I tried to do
ubuntu-bug /var/crash/<___>.crash 

... but apparently the file is malformed, so not understandable for ubuntu-bug.
Looking through the file, line 1182 has a "core dump" which then has an immense amount of data in base64 format as indicated by:
CoreDump: base64
 H4sICAAAAAAC/0NvcmVEdW1wAA==

If I'm not misinformed H4sICAAAAAAC/0NvcmVEdW1wAA== is a beginning and end marker, but there is no second instance of it... if true, then that might be a cause for ubuntu-bug having a problem with it.
$ grep -n 'H4sICAAAAAAC/0NvcmVEdW1wAA==' _usr_sbin_gdm3.0.crash 
1183: H4sICAAAAAAC/0NvcmVEdW1wAA==

a head -n 1181 >tempfile.crash allowed ubuntu-bug to at least tell that gdm3 stopped suddenly.
... attempting this now (after a long journey with gdm3 and nvidia driver reinstalls) seems to trigger a gdm3 crash again...
I have uploaded the 1181-line version of the .crash file to pastebin, for anyone interested to have a look --> https://pastebin.com/ajKsHJHy
The full file with the crash dump appears to trigger a pastebin junk filter.
So: My question is, how to handle this situation - from the command line - in a proper manner?
Note: GUI (a "dm") not available in that situation!

Crash file sending still open, any clue anyone?
I have the system up and running 100% again...
Now, what did I do to get it running again?
I wish I knew exactly what there was that remedied the problem.
Logged in using CTRL-ALT-F2 I seem to have done several things, history reveals this:
sudo apt-get reinstall gdm3  
sudo apt-get -f reinstall gdm3  
sudo apt-get purge gdm3  
sudo apt install lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter
# attempt a login, (fails!?)
sudo apt purge lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter
sudo apt install gdm3 gdm-settings' 
sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:535

With other information lookup(s) and nonworking attempts in between.
Somehow I came to believe (in the end) that the nvidia driver caused the problem,
and that it required a reinstall (clean-out) of gdm3 and it's settings...
it appears that I achieved this by first doing a purge and then install them back again.

EDIT 2024-05-20.
The problem was caused by sudo apt install fuse - to get it fixed; sudo apt purge fuse first, then work through the above.
To have a less invasive fuse, try sudo apt install libfuse2 - you MIGHT get lucky.
NOTE: fuse/libfuse2 is necessary to be able to run AppImage:s.
This script might also be an alternative (instead of the above) for running AppImage-s:
$ cat myAppRun.py 
#!/bin/env python3

import os, sys
p=os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

# https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE
# sudo apt install libfuse2 or ...

s= \
f'cd "{p}"\n' \
+'t="$(mktemp -d -p .)" && (\n' \
+'cd "$t"\n' \
+f'../{sys.argv[1]} --appimage-extract\n' \
+'cd squashfs-root/\n' \
+'./AppRun\n' \
+'cd ../..\n' \
+'rm -rf "$t" )\n'

print(s)
os.system(s)


Woah @Hannu, thank you for your posts here; you saved my day today!
I ran into this exact problem and had no idea what was going on. I had done a fresh install of 24.04 and started installing the usual dev tools and that sort of thing. All was well. Then randomly the machine wouldn't boot into graphical mode. I would have never guessed it was from fuse, but thanks to you I got that sorted out.

Those steps definitely worked for me. I tried your suggested steps bit-by-bit to try to piece together what really did it too, running each step with a reboot in between. In the end I had to do them all except the steps with lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter and ubuntu-drivers install nvidia.
Also, if it helps others, I have an onboard intel video card; no nvidia at all.

Thank a mil @Hannu - never would guess that fuse would be the cause, what I did is:
sudo apt-get purge fuse; sudo apt purge gdm3; sudo apt install gdm3 gdm-settings; sudo reboot
and I'm back in Gnome

One more thing - after removing fuse nautilus is missing (fuse installs it's own version I guess, that's probably why it messes with gdm) - also sudo apt install nautilus

Looks like this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fuse/+bug/1717878

So if so then sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-session should fix it then.

Just happened to me. This got me up and running again.

https://superuser.com/a/1863352/346288
