How to delete /dev/nvme0n1p1 where my Ubuntu install using terminal. Because I stuck the gnu grab version 2.12, how can I fixed it
Gnu gurb version 2.12 displayed.
After clicking the *Ubuntu, I will shown error:
Failed to start gdm.service - gdm Display Manager and other error will to shown.
How can I fixed this. Please  help me.

"How to delete /dev/nvme0n1p1 where my Ubuntu install using terminal" sorry but why would that fix the "failed to start gdm.service"? If you end up on a grub prompt make sure you have "secure boot" disabled and you start up using UEFI. "Failed to start gdm.service" could be due to a full root. That only requires you to boot from a live session and clear up some space. "and other error will to shown" Not good enough; we need the full text  "[FAILED] to start Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown" perhaps? ;)

FWIW: have a look here -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1512434/24-04-gdm3-crash-how-to-report-from-terminal-reporting-problem/1513745#1513745 - may be it will help you.  Note: boot into e.g. recovery console, by any means you can.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
